# AngularJS equivalent to Rails render/content_for?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Unfortunately, Bootstrap's modal require a tremendous amount of div's, making the html big and ugly.

Therefore, I'm trying to build a template in AngularJS. What I basically want is to declare a modal, that can use an already declared controller, like this, using directives:

```
<div ng-controller="SampleController as sCtrl">
  ...
  <modal-dialog>
    <modal-title> A title Here </modal-title>
    <modal-body>

      <input type="text" ng-model="sCtrl.inputOne"/>
      {{sCtrl.someTextHere}}

    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer>
      <div ng-repeat="b in sCtrl.buttons">
        <button ng-click="sCtrl.someAction(b)"></button>
      </div>
    </modal-footer>
  </modal-dialog>
</div>
```

In Rails, I would do something like:

**_modal.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal-fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-title">
          <%= yield :modal_title %>
        </div>
      </div>
      ...
        <%= yield :modal_body %>
      ...
        <%= yield :modal_footer %>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**my_view.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :modal_title do %>
  A title here
<% end %>

<%= render 'modal' %>
```

So, How could I achieve this in AngularJS? Creating nested directives, where the children will replace (or be appended in) some html tag of the parent directive, and so the angular code inside it works fine with my outer controller?

P.S.: I generally use AngularUI Bootstrap for most things, but not for modal. I found the technique and the examples more ugly and complicated than including the regular html and calling $("#modal").show() So, if it's worth it using AngularUI for this, please show me how and why.

Comment: Are you using the built-in `scope` attribute when you first declare your directive? Then you could just pass things like title as an attribute of the directive. If you could show your `app.directive` function that would be great too.

Comment: scope? yes, I use... but I can't do what I intend. It's pointless to show my code as I have no idea of what to use. i was thinking of using transclude, but I don't know how to use multiple ng transclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [hyper-content-for](https://github.com/hyperoslo/hyper-content-for-angular) might be a solution.